# jsf selectonemenu selectitems from an enum

Tags: jsf, enums, selectonemenu

Ok, I think I've seen all the matches about this in StackOverflow and other Internet sites. My code is as follows:

Class:

```
public enum pruebaEnum{PRUEBA1, PRUEBA2, PRUEBA3};
private pruebaEnum prueba;
private pruebaEnum[] pruebaList;

public pruebaEnum getPrueba() {
    return prueba;
}

public void setPrueba(pruebaEnum prueba) {
    this.prueba = prueba;
}

public pruebaEnum[] getPruebaList() {
    return pruebaEnum.values();
}

public void setPruebaList(pruebaEnum[] pruebaList) {
    this.pruebaList = pruebaList;
}
```

JSF code:

```
<t:selectOneMenu id="categorization" value="#{BookManual.prueba}">
    <t:selectItems Value="#{BookManual.pruebaList}"/>
</t:selectOneMenu>
```

The fact is I only get an empty dropbox. I don't know what I am doing wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute names are case sensitive. You used `Value`, but it's `value`.

By the way, you don't need a setter for `<f:selectItems>`. Get rid of it to save dead code and unnecessary future confusions because it's never invoked.

Comment: I changed Value with value, and the result is the same.

Comment: Works fine for me. Please mention your JSF impl/version used.